# antenna polarization trajectory

Tags: antenna, radiation

I work on simulation of kind of antenna.  How can one interpret this antenna polarization trajectory? [image]

the vertical axis label is 'X'.
If I want to plot polarization like the above figure, what are the elements
I should use in the plot? Ex-Ey or any other component

Comment: To be honest, how should we know how you can produce a figure that you present to us without context?

Comment: just interpret the figure, plotting part can be extracted out of interpretation. polarization trajectory is new for me

Comment: This kind of figure is hard to interpret without context. That why I'm asking for context, that only you can deliver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find the answer in [this](https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-26-11-2016) paper, this kind of polarization 
figure is the plot of two perpendicular component of radiated Electrical Field. when ever the elliptic schematic lead to  x axis,  the
polarization have bigger component in x direction.